# Summation of cell array of function handles

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array with size (n,1) that includes a function handle. Every cell has to include specific function handle and the summation of function handles in the previous cells. How can I perform this operation? To clarify this is an illustration.

```
A = cell(size(ones(n,1)));
for i = 1 : n
    A{i,1} = @(x) A{i-1,1} + i .* x;
end
```

How to get `A{n,1}` at `x = 2` (for example)

Comment: You cannot add function handles. You can only call them. Do you mean to add the result of applying previous function handles to the data?

Comment: A word of caution: when you create an anonymous function, any [variables in the expression](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621) will be fixed to their values at the time the function is created. This means, for example, if you go back and change `A{2,1}`, all the functions in the subsequent cells will still be using the old value for `A{2,1}` instead of the new one. You would have to recreate them to use the new value.

Answer (score 3):

You are actually pretty close, but you need to add a special case for `i = 1` and you need to call the function:

```
n = 10;
A = cell(size(ones(n,1)));

A{1,1} = @(x) 1 .* x;
for ii = 2 : n
    A{ii,1} = @(x) A{ii-1,1}(x) + ii .* x;
end
```

I replaced `i` with `ii`, to avoid confusion with complex numbers. For the case `n = 10`:

```
>> A{n}(2)

ans =

   110
```

Answer (score 2):

Recalling [@gnovice comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712715/summation-of-cell-array-of-function-handles/53714032#comment94282475_53712715), you can also just make a cell array of the handles, and then call a function that sums them up to `n`:

```
N = 10;
A = cell(N,1);
A{1} = @(x) 1.*x;
for k = 2:N
    A{k} = @(x) k.*x;
end

% the following function sums the output of A{1}(x) to A{n}(x):
f = @(n,x) sum(cellfun(@(c) c(x),A(1:n)));
```

The result:

```
>> f(5,2)
ans =
    30
>> f(N,2)
ans =
   110
```

This way, every change of the functions in `A` will have an immediate effect upon redefining `f`:

```
>> A{3} = @(x) -x;
>> f = @(n,x) sum(cellfun(@(c) c(x),A(1:n)));
>> f(N,2)
ans =
   102
>> f(5,2)
ans =
    22
```